# Java Web Start security warning despite using all-permissions and privileged action

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, java-web-start

I have set up JMS connections between my JBoss (4.2.2.GA) server and our J2SE client. The client runs via Java Web Start, and in the JNLP, I have the following:

```
<jnlp version="1.5+" codebase="$$codebase" href="start.jnlp">
    <!-- Information -->
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <resources>
        <!-- Some other non-JMS resources -->
        <jar href="concurrent.jar" />
        <jar href="jboss-common.jar" />
        <jar href="jboss-j2ee.jar" />
        <jar href="jbossmq.jar" />
        <jar href="jnpserver.jar" />
        <jar href="log4j.jar" />
    <resources>
</jnlp>
```

The JMS connection is working fine. I have successfully configured, subscribed to, and tested a JMS topic. Here is that code:

```
final String topic = ... ;
final InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
PrivilegedAction<JmsConnectionContext> action = new PrivilegedAction<JmsConnectionContext>() {

    @Override
    public JmsConnectionContext run() {
        try {
            TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");
            TopicConnection topicConnection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
            int sessionId = Client.getSession().getSessionId();
            topicConnection.setClientID("UMClient-" + sessionId);
            TopicSession session = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false,
                    TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            Topic jmsTopic = (Topic) context.lookup(topic);
            TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(jmsTopic, topic + "-" +
                    sessionId);
            subscriber.setMessageListener(new JmsTopicMessageListener());
            topicConnection.start();
            return new JmsConnectionContext(topic, topicConnection, session);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Topic creation and connection failed.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
};
return AccessController.doPrivileged(action);
```

And my JNDI properties configuration is very straightforward:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming
java.naming.provider.url=10.1.3.143:1099
```

Also, the jars have all been signed using our company certificate, which was issued via a CA (set to expire within the next few months, but it's still valid). I've also tried clearing the `javaws` cache to make sure it wasn't an outdated code issue.

So why is the warning still coming up? I'm running it as a privileged action which, as far as I understand, should just grant the code the `all-permissions` policy from the JNLP file, but yet when `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.checkConnectPermission()` gets called during the JNDI lookup, the JWS security manager brings up the security warning. Is there something else I have to configure for the JNDI lookups to have elevated connection privileges, and can I configure that over Java Web Start?

**Update**

I'm still dealing with this problem. I narrowed down the dialog to coming up when it tries to access the RMI port on the server (it's checking permission`host:1098`). I tried setting the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property to `host`, going off of the workaround listed in [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6533026). Since the first RMI lookup doesn't happen until after the client is already started, I assume that I don't need to find a way to add it to the JNLP file via a `<property>`.

Here's the stack trace from when I click "cancel" in the security warning:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 10.1.3.143:1098 connect,resolve)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.checkConnectPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:667)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.naming.LinkRefPairObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(LinkRefPairObjectFactory.java:85)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstance(NamingContext.java:1273)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1290)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1298)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:763)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.ultramain.uui.jms.JmsHelper.jndiLookup(JmsHelper.java:145)
    ...
```

So the problem is specific to RMI access. Why doesn't setting the hostname work to fix the dialog, as suggested in the workaround in the linked bug report and a few other resources I have found? Is there any other workaround to fix this?

Comment: Maybe relevant: our target environment is Java 6u17, and I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a big hack, but it's all I could find.

Going off of information [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1309803), the JWS security manager doesn't have the RMI code listed as trusted code because it was loaded under a separate class loader. Because the code didn't originate from the JNLP, JWS doesn't let it run with the `all-permissions` security.

The hacky fix for this was simply wrapping each lookup with something like:

```
Topic topic = null;
SecurityManager prevSecurityManager = System.getSecurityManager();
try {
    System.setSecurityManager(null);
    topic = (Topic) context.lookup(name);
} finally {
    System.setSecurityManager(prevSecurityManager);
}
```

Setting the `SecurityManager` to `null` bypasses the JWS security manager, letting the default one take over.

Eventually, I want to find a way to add the RMI code to the trusted codebase for the JNLP, but this solution will work in our development environments and demos until I can do that. This isn't a very secure way of doing things, especially in an application which can be multi-threaded like this. It gives a small window of opportunity where there is no security manager, so if anyone has a solution which will allow me to trust the RMI code in the JNLP configuration, post it and your answer will be accepted (provided it works of course).